# iOS Compare GPS locations

Tags: ios, gps, cllocationmanager

I'm creating an application which needs to determine if my current location (recd in didUpdateLocation:) is present among a set of geo-coordinates I have. Now I understand that comparing double/float values for equality can be error prone as the precisions involved in geo-coordinates is very high. Slight inaccuracy in the GPS can throw my algo off-track. Hence I need to compare it with some error margin.

How do I compare 2 CLLocations with a margin of error? Or determine the error in the location reading (I don't think this is possible since CLLocationManager would have rectified it).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Check if your point is within a square or circle with the side or radius of your error margin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In each `CLLocation` instance there is a property declared as `@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationAccuracy horizontalAccuracy;` What you can do is to make a routine like:

```
-(BOOL)isLocation:(CLLocation*)location inRangeWith:(CLLocation*)otherLocation{
    CLLocationDistance delta = [location distanceFromLocation:otherLocation];
    return (delta < location.horizontalAccuracy);
}
```

You can make even more complex logic as both locations have that property...

Cheers.
【ツ】

Comment: Hi Ariel. .horizontalAccuracy is a good pointer. I can use that, thanx. But my fundamental problem is I want to avoid using distanceFromLocation: Any work-arounds there?

Comment: You can calculate deltas in coordinates, but then it will be a much more complex, as the actual distance of one coordinate angle is different in meters according to the distansing from the equator.
Anyway, as far as I can tell the `distanceFromLocation:` don't have much power or CPU consumption...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CoreLocation method `distanceFromLocation:` to find the distance between the user's location and another point.  If the distance is less than whatever threshold you decide, then you can assume the locations are the same.

```
CLLocationDistance threshold = 5.0;  // threshold distance in meters

// note: userLocation and otherLocation are CLLocation objects
if ([userLocation distanceFromLocation:otherLocation] <= threshold) {
    // same location
}
```

Comment: Hi jonkroll, I've not had a look at any quantitative study which proves this, but from the look of it, Haversine formula looks complicated and distanceFromLocation: most probably uses this to calculate distance between 2 lat-longs. I want to avoid using that function on each lat-long. Any workarounds?